# Как правильно спарсить json в javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с проблемой, не умею нормально спарсить *json* в *javascript*.
Вот `json`:

```
{
  "Suicide Squard": {
    "small-link": "https://www.reg.ru/i/svg/b-header__logo_site_ru.svg",
    "title": "Suicide Squad",
    "gif": "https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png"
  },
  "Sticker Shop": {
    "small-link": "https://www.reg.ru/i/svg/b-header__logo_site_ru.svg",
    "title": "Sticker Shop",
    "gif": "https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png"
  }
}
```

Надо чтобы в конце мог делать примерно так:

```
parsed[1].small-link
```

Comment: Не до конца понимаю, почему хотите парсить объект в массив. Ну, parsed["Suicide Squard"] будет из коробки. Или у вас где-то в коде четко закреплено, что "Suicide Squard" это 1?

Answer (score 1):

Учим основы JS: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
let parsed = JSON.parse`{
  "Suicide Squard": {
    "small-link": "https://www.reg.ru/i/svg/b-header__logo_site_ru.svg",
    "title": "Suicide Squad",
    "gif": "https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png"
  },
  "Sticker Shop": {
    "small-link": "https://www.reg.ru/i/svg/b-header__logo_site_ru.svg",
    "title": "Sticker Shop",
    "gif": "https://vk.com/images/icons/head_icons.png"
  }
}`;

console.info(parsed['Suicide Squard']['small-link']);
```

Но это объект, тут не индексы, а ключи. В данном случае - названия.
Далее - нельзя обратится `data.small-link`, т. к. `-` не является допустимым идентификатором, используйте скобочную нотацию как в примере.

Comment: Спасибо!Ещё появился вопрос, например project = 3
Вызываю:
console.log(database[project]['small-link']);
TypeError: Cannot read property 'small-link' of undefined

Comment: @Kelotixy, Спасибо тут принято в плюсах выражать. Я, конечно, уже знаю что такое `project` и к чему он относится, просто притворяюсь что не знаю :) А ошибка говорит что не может взять свойство `small-link` из-за того, что `database[project]` ничего не нашёл (вернулся `undefined`).